Oracle Apex Test IR Efficiency Changes
I am using oracle apex version 23.2.3. I have a dashboard in Oracle apex that contains multiple reports. One of which is quite large and uses several page items that contain subqueries. When I run the page through the debugger, I can see that one action written session state for item P200_LD_LAST_MONTH takes over half of the total execution time (total execution time ~ 25 seconds for larger pools of data).
I did some research and I found that other's who have had this problem state it does not relate to session state at all, but the query itself.
My question is, how would I properly test the speed of these queries in oracle apex? Since my total execution time is going down with each run (without any changes), I assume apex is caching some of the data. All of my page items are set to Per Request and source queries are used Always, replacing any existing value in session state.
Any tips on optimizing apex pages when debugger doesn't seem to be too helpful?

Just a couple of things that might help:

If a page item is set to "Per Request" it means that the value of the page item is not cached. Whenever a user navigates to the page or submits the page that is a new request and the value will be recalculated. If that is what you want, then that is fine. If the value of that page does not change on page submit or when user navigates to the page then it might be better to set it to "Per Session" and it will only take long the first time. But... it will still take long.

If something takes over 20 seconds to load, even if that is just the first time, users will complain. Any page that takes over 5 seconds is considered very slow. Review the logic that you are using. Maybe data can be pre-aggregated in a table or a materialized view can be used.


